# Snake Game control help in Java/ processing

Tags: keyboard, processing

I am currently coding a basic snake game in processing and I want the snake not to move in the opposite direction it is currently moving.

The snake just stops whenever I press the opposite direction but i want the game to ignore the keypress.

```
if (keyCode == DOWN && direction != "up"){
 if (frameCount % framespeed == 0){
ypos += speed; 
}
direction = "down";
}
if (keyCode == UP && direction != "down"){
 if (frameCount % framespeed == 0){
ypos -= speed;
}
direction = "up";
}
if (keyCode == RIGHT && direction != "left"){
 if (frameCount % framespeed == 0){
xpos += speed; 
}
direction = "right";
}
if (keyCode == LEFT && direction != "right"){
 if (frameCount % framespeed == 0){
xpos -= speed; 
}
direction = "left";
}
```

Just ignore the frameCount

Comment: Java tag removed. Processing is not Java.

Comment: From `String.equals()` Processing [docs](https://processing.org/reference/String_equals_.html): "Compares two strings to see if they are the same. This method is necessary because it's not possible to compare strings using the equality operator (==)."

Comment: Thanks I tried using    !direction.equals("up")  but that doesnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should not use `==` or `!=` to compare `String` values. You need to use the `equals()` function. You've mentioned that you tried this in the comments, but then please update your post to include a new [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note that this should **not** be your full snake game. It should be a minimal example. For example, come up with a simple sketch that shows a direction on screen (in text, not something moving). Change the direction with the arrow keys. Make it so you can't change the direction to the opposite.

Another thing you need to consider is that if the snake is pointing up, the user can press right and then down to reverse the direction of the snake. If they do that fast enough, it will happen faster than your frame rate, and the snake will reverse direction.

There are a number of ways to fix this, and Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z intsead" type questions. So please [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and [debug your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) so you understand exactly what's happening. If you still can't get it figured out, then post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question post and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. This was my first question here so i am sorry about that